# In the JUnit test I need expected output [null] but it gives only null. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

This is my Testing Code. And I want that if my Other_comapanies field is empty then I should delete it or else I should leave it.

I am Creating an object and filling all the fields in it. And I am storing null in front of other_comapanies field. When I test my code So expected output like this [null] and my actual output is 'null' like this. So, How should I fix it?

```
 @Test
    public void shouldRemoveOtherCompaniesOnUpdatePreProcessing(){
        List<BaseEntity> baseEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        BaseEntity baseEntity = new ContactEntity();
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("first_name", "Sample");
        data.put("last_name", "Contact");
        data.put("email", "sample.contact@gmail.com");
        data.put("id", 12345);
        data.put("company_id", 1234);
        List<Map<String, Object>> secondaryCompaniesWithNotRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> secondaryCompany1 = new HashMap<>();
        secondaryCompany1.put("company_id",1234L);
        secondaryCompaniesWithNotRemove.add(secondaryCompany1);
        baseEntity.setData(data);
        baseEntities.add(baseEntity);
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put(PreferenceKeyConstants.ENTITIES_TO_SYNC, "ACCOUNTS");

        when(contactEntityEndpoint.findById(baseEntity.getId().toString(),null)).thenReturn((ContactEntity) baseEntity);

        List<Map<String, Object>> expectedSecondaryCompaniesIsRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        expectedSecondaryCompaniesIsRemoved.add(null);

        contactCompanyFieldsPreProcessor.doOnUpdatePreProcessing(baseEntities, new ArrayList<>(), options);
        Map<String, Object> preProcessedBaseEntityData = baseEntities.get(0).getData();
        assertEquals(expectedSecondaryCompaniesIsRemoved, preProcessedBaseEntityData.get("other_companies"));
    }
```

My testing output is :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[null]
Actual   :null
```

How Can I fix it? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are comparing `null` with a `List` containing a `null` value. Which are different things. You should just write `assertNull(preProcessedBaseEntityData.get("other_companies"));`.